# Nslookup can't find srv records after server move

Tags: networking, dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I just moved my non-profit's server from Windows 2003 to 2012. Everyone can log in, but I'm having trouble joining computers to the domain and netlogon throws an error every so often. I think some thing's wrong with my DNS records. When I run nslookup, it correctly resolves the domain and DNS server correctly. However, if I type type=all, it returns
dc.domain.org non-existent domain. I've checked everywhere I can think of to fix this problem. My SRV records exist in the Forward DNS folders, host names resolve correctly, the server's nic has the box check that says 'register with the domain', the DNS server is set to automatically update (secure) with Active Directory, and the server is the only DNS sever on the network. Everything else works correctly. Clients get IP addresses, can log in, can access files, and hostnames all resolve properly. I can't figure out why nslookup fails. I'm assuming once I fix that, netlogon and other related services will work correctly.

Network Specs:
Single server running Server 2012
Services:
      Active Directory
      DHCP
      DNS
      File Server
      Print Server

Comment: Not sure if it contributes to the problem or not, but have you changed over the Operations Masters etc...?

Comment: Try type=srv. If that doesn't work, you should look for type=soa and type=ns with domain.org.

Comment: @EdG, all 5 FMSO roles have been moved and the old server decommissioned.

Comment: @ aecolley, here's what I get no matter what I try

Comment: Sorry. Some caught me and it timed out. Anyway,command sequence:
nslookup
Server: dc.domain.org
Address: ip
>type=ns
Server: dc.domain.org
Address: ip
****dc.domain.org can't find type=ns: Non-existent Domain
Same thing happens if I try with domain.org specified.

Answer (score 0):

Nslookup is failing because it is trying to be too helpful.  It is misleading you, almost certainly in this case since everything is otherwise working just fine.  Use a proper DNS debugging tool like `dig` instead, which forces you to ask specific DNS questions and requires you understand what you are asking.  It doesn't append search list entries (almost certainly the cause of your troubles) and it doesn't try to reverse-map the IP address in the DNS configuration to get it's friendly name, both the most confounding and misleading things nslookup does to people.

You can get `dig` here:  http://www.isc.org/downloads/, expand the BIND area, select the Current Stable and download the zip file (for Windows).  It is a full-blown DNS server package, but you can install it in "Tools Only" mode and you'll get just `dig` and `host` and some other debug tools for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your mistake was only in that you didn't type "set" before "type=SRV".    So nslookup command "set type=SRV" is correct 
:)